# a / b != a^2/b^2

Tags: graphing-functions

I am trying to populate a radar/spider chart and increase how drastic the difference between numbers are.

I thought that using squares would increase the difference between two numbers but it seems to decrease the difference in this case.

```
playstyle = {'infantry': 267, 'archers': 321, 'cavalry': 324, 'monks': 313, 'siege': 328}
```

267 / 321 = 0.831775700934

267^2 / 321^2 = 0.691850816665

Why does squaring the numbers make the difference between the numbers smaller? How would you explain this?

What is the best way to exaggerate difference between these numbers for displaying them on a chart?

Here is what the current chart looks like:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  If $0\lt \alpha\lt 1$, then $0\lt\alpha^2\lt\alpha$

Comment: In light of what @J.W.Tanner has said. You can try taking the square root or the cube root instead.

Comment: Well, it *does* make it more drastic. To keep it simple, say we have `{'infantry': 1, 'archers': 10}`. The true ratio is $1/10 = 0.1$, whereas the squared ratio is $1/100 = 0.01$. In other words, in the squared ratio, the archers will look *one hundred* times bigger than the infantry instead of only ten times. Isn't that drastic?

Comment: @Théophile yes but not visually